# html, send a form via post or get according to submit button

Tags: html

I wonder if there is a clean way to do an html form that will get posted if the user pushes a post button and that could be sent as well with the get method if the user pushes a get button. I need this because I would like to show a form which can both enter new data or search for existing data in the database. If the user wants to enter data in the database they could fill the form and send via a 'send' button (POST) and if they are not sure what they want they can partly fill the form and push the search button (GET) to receive some insights on what is in the database. From what I know the method is defined for the form, not for the submit buttons. Any idea how I could do that without javascript? or with javascript?

Comment: can you tag you question with javascript/jquery (for example) if you are looking for solutions that utilize those.

Comment: I'd rather have a pure html solution. If the only valid solution uses javascript then I'll accept it that's why I put 'with javascript'.

Comment: I don't know of a method that would utilize HTML only. But I have responded with a JS solution. If you aren't already using jQuery there's no point in using it as the JS will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you shouldn't need this functionality, I will answer your question anyway.

Here. 
First you should assign an ID to the form. Our sample form will have the ID 'YYYY'.

```
<form action="whatever" id="YYYY" method="" >



<input type="button" onClick="usingget();" value="GET" />
<input type="button" onClick="usingpost();" value="POST" />

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function usingget() {
document.getElementById('YYYY').method = 'GET';
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('YYYY').submit();
}},1000);
function usingpost() {
document.getElementById('YYYY').method = 'POST';
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('YYYY').submit();
}},1000);
</script>
```

Now, when you click one of the buttons it will change the method.
EDIT: There is now a 1 second delay because I am tired and unsure of whether or not the form will submit before the method is changed without it.

Comment: Isn't there some danger that the form would be submitted (because they are 'submit' buttons) by whatever the default method is before it is changed? Perhaps another option would be to use standard 'input' buttons then use the functions to submit the form.

Comment: This looks good, although maybe what @blankabout says should be taken into account. Just a question, why do you say I "shouldn't need this functionality"?

Comment: That is what came to my mind originally when I did something similar for myself. I needed a delay for other reasons unrelated to this though so that solved my problem. Maybe you should just make the buttons call the functions which then change the method, delay and then submit the form. I was wrong about you not needing this functionality also.

Comment: @JosiahSouth ho well no problem about that, just if you think it's not the way to go then I'd rather hear your point of view. I thought a form that can do both updating the database and searching would be neat for the user since the fields are the same.

Comment: @Bastian I'm honestly not sure whether or not that is a good practice. I haven't had the need to. Maybe someone else will chime in. Also, small questions like whether or not that is a good practice are great to ask in the chat rooms. That's where I would go to ask. Also I have added a 1 second delay which may or may not be needed. It is 2:46am here and I don't remember whether or not it would change the method or submit first.

Comment: Let us know if it worked and be sure to pick a best answer if there was one ;).